# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory but file exists

Tags: php

i have this files on my web folder.
but when i try to login it returns

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

in localhost it works perfectly

[image: ftp screenshot]

below is my code:

after successful login it redirects to this page.

```
<?php
        if (!empty($errors)) {
          echo $errors;
        } else{
          echo "Please wait while the browser redirects you to our Booking System<br><br><img src=/../images/load.gif>
            ";
            header("location:loading.php");
        }
 ?>
```

Comment: Add code of loading.php.

Comment: This is a database error, not a php one. Add the database code and sql. What do you use for error handling, exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here may be that you are running this php code from another directory and the loading.php is not in it (for example if the code above is in the php folder). To fix this i suggest you use the absolute path, something like this :

```
 header("location: http://yoursite.com/loading.php");
```

PS: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] is a problem with the connection to mysql server.